# Which chapter of the manga does Kirishima unbreakable form appear?

Tags: my-hero-academia

The Boku No Hero Academia wikia states that Kirishima has an unbreakable form, which is seen in the manga. So far in the anime until season 3 episode 20 we havent seen it. Which chapter of the manga does Kirishima unbreakable form appear and it's far of close of what the chapters of the manga the anime are covering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kirishima unbreakable form appears in Chapter 133. The anime is currently at chapter 110 and will likely end just before the arc in which this happens.